# How do i count same values in an array and store it to a variable?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

```
$items = explode(',',$product); // values is 4,2,4,2,2,4

$unique_items=array_unique($items); // gives me 4,2
```

What code should be next to give me 4 = 3 , 2 = 3 and store the number of values to a variable?

Comment: Do a loop, for n-times (n being the number of elements in $items), then. extract each character at $i ($i would be the current number of loops, also the offset into the string, that is you do `for($i=0; i<count($items); $i++){...}`) and match that character to each element inside $unique_items, increase a counter variable each time the character inside $unique_items and $items[$i] match, and that's it! You can figure out the code yourself, since I'm a bit rusty with php commands.

Answer (score 56):

see: [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/function.array-count-values.php)

Like:

```
$occurences = array_count_values($items);
print_r($occurences);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [4] => 3
    [2] => 3
)
```

Usage:

```
echo $occurences[4]; // outputs 3
```

Comment: how  to store the value of 3 to a variable? tnx

Comment: @yohdaman See the updated code. You have all the information in `$occurences`. If you want to access them, use: `$occurences[4]` for example.

Comment: tnx to all!! very much appreciated. =)

Answer (score 4):

You're probably looking for array_count_values() function.