# Efficient way of counting repetitions on a PHP int array

Tags: php, arrays, count, processing-efficiency, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do i count same values in an array and store it to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408095/how-do-i-count-same-values-in-an-array-and-store-it-to-a-variable)

I want to know if there's any efficient way to count repetitions on a PHP int array.

In a very big large array (1 million positions), with numbers from 0 to the maximum int size.

I just want to know how many times each number appears on the array but in the most efficient way.

For example:

```
$i[0] = 1
$i[1] = 1
$i[2] = 2
$i[3] = 2
$i[4] = 6
$i[5] = 1
```

1 = 3 times

2 = 2 times

6 = 1 time

Thanks.

Comment: And you have no idea how to solve this?

Comment: I know how to solve it Gumbo :) The thing is, i just wanted to make sure about which is the best and most efficient way to solve it with big numbers.

Answer (score 15):

You forget that you are programming in PHP. PHP has a function for everything.

E.g. for your particular problem you can just use [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/array_count_values) :)

Comment: +1 for *PHP has a function for everything*.

Answer (score 0):

A foreach statement:

```
for($x=1; $x<=1000; $x++){
    $count=0;
    foreach($i as $y){
        if($y==$x){
            $count+=1;
        }
    }
    print($y . "=" . $count . "times");
}
```