# With 2 arrays, check how many identical elements

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays, example:

```
$array1 = array('hello1', 'hello2', 'hello3');
$array2 = array('world1', 'world2', 'hello3');
```

How can I count how many identical elements occur in these 2 arrays? So in this case, the value would be `1`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, please show your code/effort and what the actual problem is.

Comment: The problem is clearly layed out. :) maybe do a foreach on one array, then check if it contains the elements of the other array. But there must be a better way.

Comment: @GaryWoods Of course there is. Merge and sort both arrays, then traverse the result.

Comment: @EugeneSh. How do you mean? What's traverse? Post answer.

Comment: @GaryWoods No, I won't. See the first comment.

Comment: @EugeneSh. php provides `array_intersect()`, no need to use `array_merge()`.

Comment: @Ray If the OP is not interested in algorithms, that's perfect..

Comment: [**How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3933332)

Comment: What does "identical element" mean? Same index, same value? Or just same value anywhere?

Comment: So similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13413465/1677912) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6408095/1677912) that it doesn't deserve to be a different question. It's not an EXACT duplicate of either, but it would take less effort to adapt the answers from those questions that it did to post this variation of the theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform an `array_intersect()` then call `count()` the number of elements:

```
    $values_in_all_arrays = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
    echo count($values_in_all_arrays);
```

Use the `php` built in functions when at all possible.

Comment: I don't know if I got it right, but this might not give the correct value, for example: add one more `hello3` to `array1` and the output will be `2`. (I understood that the op wants to know how many duplicates there are, not how many times each duplicates... - of course, that's just my understanding).

Comment: If i got it correctly, just changing to `array_intersect(array_unique($array1), array_unique($array2));` should do the trick. (Outputs `1` because only one value is duplicated, doesn't matter how many times)

Comment: @FirstOne  you could just do a single `array_unique` on the final intersect built `array()`  like `array_unique(array_intersect($array1,array2));`

Answer (score 0):

use array_intersect() function to get common values

Answer (score 0):

Try this naïve code out:

```
$count = 0;
foreach($array1 as $val1) {
   foreach($array2 as $val2) {
      if ($val1 == $val2) {
         $count++;
      }
   }
}
```

I am not of PHP knowledgeable much. But looping through array is same as in other languages.

Edit: I have found the following way:

```
$difference = array_diff($array1,$array2);
$count = count($difference);
```

Comment: In the first code with the `foreach`, the output will always count the same number of items in the array or more. You are looping the same array twice (`$array1` and `$array1`). I assume that you wanted to use `$array2` in the inner loop...