# Count same dates inside an array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Im just a beginner in php can someone help me to get the count of the same dates in array? Also I've a search a function related to my problem but I still cant.

I've tried to use `array_values` to count dates but I can't get it.

```
$dates = [
    "2019-07-01",
    "2019-07-01",
    "2019-07-02",
    "2019-07-02",
    "2019-07-02"
];
```

return

```
Array
(
    [2019-07-01] => 2
    [2019-07-02] => 2
    [2019-07-03] => 1
)
```

Thanks for the effort.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408095/how-do-i-count-same-values-in-an-array-and-store-it-to-a-variable).

Comment: @Andrei ah, les mark as dupe^^ :)

Comment: if the answer is same then that doesn't mean i copied ok

Comment: Thanks i dont know about array count values

Answer (score 0):

Please try this it will return the expected output

```
print_r(array_count_values($dates));
```

Comment: linked dupe has this answer ..